# Убрать галочку с категорий верхнего уровня

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Всем привет, есть такая проблема. Импортировал товары через плагин поставщика и это плагин проставляет галочку в категории верхнего и нижнего уровня. Мне нужно чтобы галочка на категории верхнего уровня убралась, лучше через код так как при следующем обновлении все повториться.

Comment: Если это плагин поставщика, то все вопросы к нему. Или же взять другой плагин для импорта.

Comment: Нет, нужна через хук убрать галочки с категорий верхнего уровня.